# Check if Apple watch is currently paired with iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos

I'm trying to check in an 'independent' WatchKit app if my current Apple watch is paired with an iPhone.

I've tried to do this by using the WatchConnectivity framework, but unfortunately this framework doesn’t support the isPaired method on watchOS. Also, the isReachable method is not applicable for this app, because there is no counterpart app on the iPhone.

Any solutions or workarounds are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly import SDK

```
import WatchConnectivity
```

Then implement session activation request

```
if WCSession.isSupported() { // check if the device support to handle an Apple Watch
    let session = WCSession.default
    session.delegate = self
    session.activate() // activate the session
}
```

Then implement methods from `WCSessionDelegate`

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    if activationState == .activated && session.isPaired { // Check if the iPhone is paired with the Apple Watch
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel. As I mentioned, isPaired method is not available in watchOS.